# Rails folder to put pre-generated html/css/images accessible to the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my application I have to periodically download reports from an external service. The basic structure is a few folders, each containing it's own index.html with css and images.
Where should I put those folders in order to my users be able to access it? I will provide the url, no need to list files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to put that other content in your app, it goes in the `public` folder within your application.

If I have a file in my app like this:

```
public/external/index.html
```

Then end users should see it when they hit:

```
http://application.com/external/
```

...without invoking any of your application's code.